# How to convert encrypted BYTES to BITS Python?

Tags: python, encryption, byte, bit

I am working in Python 3.7 and I would like to convert to bits an encoded bytes.

First I convert the **msg** and **key** (*bits to bytes*). Then I encrypt the msg with the key. After this, I would like to convert the encrypted msg to bits.

```
text = "1100.." #256 bits
key = "0010..." #128 bits

msg = int(plain, 2).to_bytes((len(plain) + 7) // 8, 'big') #to bytes
key = int(key, 2).to_bytes((len(key) + 7) // 8, 'big') #to bytes
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB) 
encoded = cipher.encrypt(msg)
```

Comment: your question doesnt really make sense ... you mean you want to convert `"\x0f" => "00001111"`? I guess you maybe want `a_chr="\xf2";print("{0:08b}".format(ord(a_chr)))`

Comment: yes, is this, but there are 16 bytes.

Comment: `for a_chr in my_bytes: print("{0:08b}".format(ord(a_chr)))`